# JQuery success callback isn't being called or?

Tags: jquery, html

I have searched a lot of threads but i can't find any answer that suits me. Now I will try to explain my problem.

I have a simple jQuery script that does a little ajax request. its simple like this:

```
print("
<script>
    function buscaCaracteristicas(idTotalizador){  
        var target = '../../ajax/doSomeSearch.php';
        $.ajax({
            url: target,                 
            //dataType: 'html',
            dataType: 'text',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(msg){
                alert(msg);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
");
```

And the PHP page does this:

```
<?php
    $ret = "<p>hello world</p>";
    exit($ret);
?>
```

I have tried putting the return data on an HTML element via $.html(msg) too.
Problem is: alert or the $.html() on callback NEVER fires although on firebug I can check the request has the return code 200 OK.

Notice that the function code is wrapped into a PHP print("") command and the return dataType is HTML which is what I really need to get (can't use JSON).

Any miraculous advice? Thanks in advance.

Solved: changing dataType to 'text' according to Splash-X advices it worked.

Comment: Have you checked: 1. That the function is called (alert on top). 2. That the script is embedded properly in the page (view source). 3. That the `doSomeSearch.php` page is actually called (view request logs/write to log). And for the sake of being nice, add ` type="text/javascript"` to the script tag :)

Comment: What is the type of data you're returning? Even if you get a 200 it doesn't mean the parser was able to read the results as HTML. Try adding in a "error" function as well. And maybe comment out the dataType to see if that fixes it.

Comment: @Aidiakapi - function is being called, script is ok on source, php page is being called too. I've added the type atribute but nothing.

Comment: @Splash - I tried putting the error callback and it started to show the alert. But, why is it going to error callback if the call is returning ok? I even check on firebug and the request is bringing the answer ok. Why?

Comment: @vambora It could be because the data type returned by the page doesn't match the data type you've specified in your AJAX request. It could also be that there is no content. Have you used Fiddler or FireBug to inspect the AJAX response to see the content and headers?

Comment: Finally worked. according to your advices, i changed the dataType from 'html' to 'text' and now it is displaying correct on alert, correct on the html element and popping up on success callback. I will pay more attention to this dataType thing from now on. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: @vambora you can also omit the dataType property and jQuery will attempt to auto-detect the format of the request.

Comment: @vambora If Splash-X's answer worked, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've tracked the issue down to the dataType attribute on the AJAX request:

```
 print(" 
 <script> 
     function buscaCaracteristicas(idTotalizador){   
         var target = '../../ajax/doSomeSearch.php'; 
         $.ajax({ 
             url: target,                  
             dataType: 'html' ,
             type: 'POST', 
             success: function(msg){ 
                 alert(msg); 
             } 
         }); 
     } 
 </script> 
 ");
```

Our suggestion was to add an error handeler and change the dataType:

```
      $.ajax({ 
             url: target,                  
             dataType: 'html' ,
             type: 'POST', 
             success: function(msg){ 
                 alert(msg); 
             },
             error: function(){
                  alert('error occured');
             }
         });
```

After getting the error alert we suggested removing the dataType property and letting jQuery auto-determine it OR changing it to text. The OP decided to specify the type as text and it worked:

```
      $.ajax({ 
             url: target,                  
             dataType: 'text',
             type: 'POST', 
             success: function(msg){ 
                 alert(msg); 
             }
         });
```

The issue was resolved

Comment: Glad that works, the `return ` should work within a php function which is I guess how I thought you had your php setup.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

try this way :

```
<?php
    $ret = "<p>hello world</p>";
    echo $ret;
?>
```

and see the result

UPDATED code:

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['value_s']))
        {
          $ret = "<p>hello world</p>";
          echo $ret;
        }
        else {
        echo "Nothing received !";
       }
?>
```

and the javascript:

```
$.ajax({
            url: target,                 
            //dataType: 'html',
            data: { "value_s":true},   //or something different value for `value_s`
            dataType: 'text',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(msg){
                alert(msg);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need your php page to return the value of `$ret` to your ajax call; try the following:

```
<?php
    $ret = "<p>hello world</p>";
    return $ret;
?>
```

Comment: Using "return" instead of "exit" made the request return nothing instead the string it was bringing =[